# Usage of Interface package results in issubclass() error

Tags: python, interface

Im currently working on a project where we decided to use the [interface](https://github.com/ssanderson/interface) library instead of `abc`. However, when I run my program, the following error pops up:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "runner.py", line 1, in <module>
    from exchanges import *
  File "/Users/**/Projects/jimmy/characterlib/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from exchanges import hitbtc
  File "/Users/**/Projects/jimmy/characterlib/soldier.py", line 5, in <module>
    class Soldier(implements(ICharacter)):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/interface/interface.py", line 490, in implements
    if not issubclass(I, Interface):
TypeError: issubclass() arg 1 must be a class
```

Now my setup here is really basic:

soldier.py:

```
from interface import implements, Interface
import characterlib.ICharacter as ICharacter

class Soldier(implements(ICharacter)):
```

ICharacter:

```
from interface import Interface

class ICharacter(Interface):
    def walk(self): pass
```

**init**.py:

```
import characterlib.ICharacter
import characterlib.Soldier
```

now as you can see, very simple setup, however, I can't manage to get it to run properly. How is this possible?

Is there anyone with some more experience on this topic?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `import`s are slighty wrong.

```
import characterlib.ICharacter as ICharacter
```

means that `ICharacter` is a module, not the interface. Just change the class declaration to solve that:

```
class Soldier(implements(ICharacter.ICharacter)):
    def walk(self):
        pass
```